# Apple Push Notification setting up Remote Notifications method overrides other methods

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have properly set up my app for `Remote Notifications` with the method

`func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`

and it processes it correctly now every time the app receives an `Apple Push Notification`.

But my issue is that this method is being called in all instances now.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` does not seem to be called anymore? Or the `launchOptions` is coming up empty?

Basically I used the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` as a catch all to process any incoming notifications which is my intended purpose, but then when I click the notification itself, it fires the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` again. Thus processing the notification twice, which I do not want.

So this is how I want my app to handle notifications:

- Anytime a notification is received, would like to automatically process the notification in the background
- When user clicks notification from outside app, to run a different method than the `didReceiveRemoteNotification`
- When user is inside app, to run a different method than the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not allow what you want. Push notifications work in the following way

1) When the application is not running, and the user clicks a notification, the application is launched and the payload of the notification is loaded in the function **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**.

2) When the application is running in background, and the user clicks a notification, the application becomes active and the function **didReceiveRemoteNotification** is called. Now this function contains the payload of the notification.

3) When the application is running and a push notification is called, the function **didReceiveRemoteNotification** is called and this function contains the payload of the notification.

4) When the app is running in background or inactive and notification is received, nothing can be done with the notifications until the user clicks the notification