# Execute function when Local Notitcation pops not when user clicks notification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I want to execute a **Function** when user receives `Local Notification` not when user clicks the `Notification`. I have saved data in `core data` and I have to update column taking identifier from `local notifcation` when the `app is terminate` not in the `background mode`. Is it possible to do that when app is terminate or not? If possible then how do I do that?

Would love to hear your opinions from you guys. Thankyou.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which method will be triggered when the notification received on iPhone(not after the notification is tapped and opened)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257124/which-method-will-be-triggered-when-the-notification-received-on-iphonenot-afte)

Comment: It does not help when the app is terminated and I've updated the question @PGDev. Thank you