# APNS get all push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsuserdefaults

[image: Notifications badge]

The server will push a notification when the user start to follow or nego.

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` when the user tap on the notification, this block will be executed, and I will get the notification info.

Currently I'm facing a problem, when there are more than 1 notification being pushed, when the user tap on the **first** one, then the **second** one won't be executed. Sometime user don't tap on the notification item in notification centre, but open the app directly, then `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` totally not executed.

Is there any way to get ALL notifications so that I can store the info into `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869377/apple-push-notification-setting-up-remote-notifications-method-overrides-other-m/29869514#29869514

Comment: @FawadMasud that means if user don't click on the notification, but click on the app icon instead, then nothing will happen?

Answer (score -1):

Case 1:

When the app is not in memory(neither in background mode nor in foreground mode) the user has two choices

1. either open the app by clicking on the notification received
2. or open the app directly by clicking on the app icon

In these cases

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

is called where you can get the notification (if any) using this

```
NSDictionary* remoteNotification=[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

Case 2:

But when the app is either in background or in foreground mode, then

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is executed, so there you can fetch your data with respect to the notification received.
And if in these modes also user tries to click on the notification then again

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

is called and there you can handle the notification data like in Case 1.

Hope this will help.

Comment: When the app is in foreground, and there are 10 notifications, the user tap on any one of them, is it possible to get all notifications?

Comment: @JsLim the notification on which you will tap, you will only get that notification's data  ,for  rest of the notifications  you may pull them from server .

Comment: how to pull them from server? Because I didn't store the flag on server. Can I pull the notification from apns server?

Comment: you can ask your server guy about pulling the specific notification .

Comment: As in my case I usually use date-time parameters comparing them from database and server.And No, you can't get them from APNS server.APNS server doesn't store more than  max. 2 notifications .

Comment: I'm the server guy, thought want to do it locally. anyway thanks

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to manage it into iOS app locally? i mean i want the same that there are 10 notifications, the user tap on any one of them, is it possible to get all notifications data?

Comment: @Shilpa Can u explain what exactly you want to do, since for every notification you can individually get the data?

Comment: @sandeepaggarwal i want all notification data by tapping on anyone notification in Notification center for any single app.

Comment: @Shilpa, you can get the modified_on property from the tapped notification and fetch all the notifications from server whose modified_on property is less than the current one.For that a modified_on property has to be there in the notification you got and that can be done from server side.Hope this will help you.