# didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHandler is not getting called in background for silent push

Tags: ios, background, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So I have added `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate to handle silent push notification

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`

This method should be invoked in the background to update the content before notifying the user, so that the user can open the application and be presented with new content immediately.

But this method is never getting called in background. I have tried to debug the issue but no success. Surprisingly this method is getting called properly if my app is in foreground and I am easily able to check `content-available` to update the UI.

Can anyone please help me with this issue that why `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is not getting called in background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was related to incorrect payload.

I was getting `content-available` outside aps instead it should be part of aps.

Incorrect payload:

```
{
   "_" = "asd-dfsd-werdsf";
   aps =     {
   };
   "content-available" = 1;
}
```

Correct payload:

```
    {
       "_" = "asd-dfsd-werdsf";
       aps =     {
       "content-available" = 1;
       };
    }
```

Comment: Reading the documentation before random coding helps some times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Enable 'Remote Notifications' in 'Background Modes' of 'Capabilities' tab in xcode.

For more information see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30785440/3632958)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Both are already enabled. I am using performFetchWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler for background fetch which is working fine.